# How would someone transition from the business sector to academic research?

Tags: research-process, masters, computer-science, theory

I am a junior undergraduate at an accredited college in the United States majoring in a Bachelor of Science in Computer Science program. Currently, I work at a for-profit business to gain some programming experience. In the future, I would like to enroll in a good Master of Science in Computer Science program. After that, I would like to work as a researcher studying computer science theory to improve human understanding of computation.

Is there a general way to transition to research after undergraduate study and, if so, are there any particular mental tools that I should acquire that would be in my best interest for research? For example, mental tools would be something like a methodology to writing papers, and another could be a framework to acquiring research grants from the government.

Comment: The question is not "how?", but "why?", in view of the success of industry-based research in intelligence research :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a general way to transition to research after undergraduate study

Usually the general way to transition to research is to do research under the supervision of an experienced researcher. (Either within the context of graduate school, or outside it.)

> are there any particular mental tools that I should acquire that would be in my best interest for research

Yes, there are many, and they vary by discipline. You would learn what tools you need for your particular research and develop those tools by conducting research under supervision of someone more experienced in doing research in your field.

Comment: Okay. Would you say that such supervision is hierarchical or lateral?